# Прилагательные к слову "жнец"

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, выбор-слов, значение-слов, прилагательные

Как правильно написать в предложении: жнецовый, жнеческий или жнецовский?

**Жнецовый карательный выход на поле боя.**
Да, можно написать так: Карательный выход жнецов на поле боя.
Но мне интересно, как такие слова правильно писать в первом примере?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала посмотрим в словарях.

ЖНЕЦ, -а, *м.* Тот, кто жнёт (см. жать2). || *ж.* жница, -ы.
|| *прилагательное* [**жнецовский**](https://www.vedu.ru/expdic/8326/), -ая, -ое (толковый словарь).

[**жнецовый**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=jFDkhaolkx0C&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=GNjp_2k2Ng&sig=LaDJvk3Lg3hD4wd-L2onlaWuf9E&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDn-O5y-ncAhWCCJoKHbVIALgQ6AEwDXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false), жатвенный (К. Е. Георг. Ручной латино-русский словарь. 1847).

[**жнецкий**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/220731/%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9), синоним: жнецовский (В. Н. Тришин. Словарь синонимов).

Прилагательного ***жнеческий*** в словарях нет. Будем считать его неологизмом.
После долгих поисков оно обнаружилось вот в таком контексте (не комментирую):

*В тёмной лодке по тёмной Неве,

в тёмной лодке, гнилой, деревянной

словно жнеческий серп по траве

мы плывём. Как кораблики в ванной.*
[Татьяна Богатырёва](http://geniusloci.io/content/stikhi-2013)

Если бы мне пришлось выбирать, я бы остановилась на прилагательном *жнецкий*.
Но лучше все-таки так: *выход жнецов, отряд жнецов, полчище жнецов, битва жнецов.*

Тут просматривается аналогия со словом "боец": отряд или группа бойцов (никто не говорит бойцовый отряд, бойцовая группа).

Answer (score 0):

Ююки, ваша фраза просто чудовищна по своему смыслу, тут дело не в форме слова.

Прилагательное от слова "жнец"- **жнецовский** или **жнецкий**. Оба варианта редко используется, и их не во всяком словаре найдешь (у Тришина есть), поэтому лучше обходиться без них.
Но дело даже не в этом. Боюсь, вы совершенно неправильно понимаете слово "жнец". ***Жнецы - люди, занимающиеся уборкой урожая зерновых*** (преимущественно серпами), что им вообще делать на поле боя?!

Каратели - они и есть каратели. Впрочем, на поле боя им тоже как-то особо желать нечего, это специальные бригады, которые "воюют" с мирным населением, в крайнем случае - с нерегулярными формированиями (партизанами, мятежниками).

Есть еще мародеры - в каком-то смысле их можно сравнить со "жнецами", но они тоже не каратели.

Вам стоит хорошо подумать над смыслом своей фразы. Или пояснить её на другом языке.

Comment: Касательно формулировки этого, на первый взгляд, ужасного предложения, хотел бы прояснить, что прилагательное "жнец" было в контексте названия специализации  класса в компьютерной игре, где данные игровые персонажи "жнецы" занимаются как раз войной. Ни чего общего не имея с описанными Вами уборщиками урожая.